# Rotating points 90 degrees

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm building a paint-esque program where the user can draw shapes like rectangles and ellipses on the canvas. These shapes have two coordinates stored, the corner from when the user started to draw it and the corner where the user stopped drawing it. I want to be able to rotate these shapes 90 degrees clockwise around the center of the bitmap they are drawn on, this bitmap is 600 x 600 pixels large. How can I transform the avaliable coordinates of these shapes so that they appear rotated 90 degrees.

This is the code that I have been trying to make work:

```
foreach (TekeningElement t in getekende_elementen)
    {
        int x_begin = t.GetBeginPunt.X;     //store x coordinate of starting point
        int y_begin = t.GetBeginPunt.Y;     //store y coordinate of starting point
        int x_eind = t.GetEindPunt.X;       //store x coordinate of end point
        int y_eind = t.GetEindPunt.Y;       //store y coordinate of end point
        int x_verschil = x_eind - x_begin;      //calculate width
        int y_verschil = y_eind - y_begin;      //calculate height
        t.SetBeginPunt = new Point(600 - x_begin - y_verschil, x_begin);        //set new starting point
        t.SetEindPunt = new Point(600 - x_eind + y_verschil, x_eind);           //set new end point
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can rotate the graphics object/its output or the points. The former is done with [g.RotateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) the latter with [Matrix.transformpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.transformpoints?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: new Point(600 - y_begin, x_begin) and new Point(600 - y_eind, x_eind)